# With rules to categorize emails into folders, how to receive notifications for new email, and list all the emails in all the folders?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2016

In Outlook 2016, I created some rules to automatically move emails received in Inbox to self-created folders, according to who the senders are.

1. Now when Outlook receives a new email and move it to a folder according to some rule, it doesn't notify me. Can it notify me for any incoming email, regardless of whether it is subject to some rule or not and then moved to a folder or stay in Inbox?
2. Now I can only manage to list all the emails in a folder in a single view in time reverse order.
   Is it possible to list all the emails, regardless in which folders they are stored, in a single view, in reverse time order?

Thanks.

Comment: Please try and ask one question at a time, otherwise it is too broad.

Answer (score 1):

1. Yes. Just check the "display a Desktop Alert" action in each of your rules.
2. Yes. Just create a Search Folder without any specific criteria. In this folder you'll get all of the emails in mailbox and you can sort them as you like.

Comment: Thanks. In the method in your part 2, when creating a Search Folder, how can i not specify any criteria?